# optimizing insertions in a mysql database on c#

Tags: c#, mysql, database, insert

I insert rows into my database in two very different and separated use cases:

1. Inserting 5000 rows all at once
2. inserting 1-10 rows in separate calls many times per second

In both situations I currently use an approach similar to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-prepared-preparing.html. And many of the posts on stackoverflow seem to follow if you google `multirow insert c# mysql`.

I feel as though the approach im using isnt optimal for either of my use cases, especially 1. I cannot insert from a csv though. Is there a speedier approach?

Comment: Prepare a statement, start a transaction, insert X rows, commit, repeat. This approach spends 1 HDD I/O for inserting X rows, thus optimally using the HDD bandwith allowing for optimum insertion rate.

Comment: @Mjh Is there a straightforward way for multiple insert in one execute? mysqls own page is looping with 1 at a time so I assumed otherwise

Comment: No, one execute = one insert. The big idea is that you are able to repeat the execute in a loop. It's the optimal way of dealing with inserts. If you wrap the loop with a transaction/commit, you instruct MySQL to spend 1 disk I/O for all those inserts you executed in the loop.

Comment: @Mjh what about `INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b,c) VALUES(1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9);` ? Still treated as one insert at a time?

Comment: It is, but it's more complex to parse (for MySQL) and you are increasing the network packet length since you're sending all in one go. Preparing the statement once, biding the parameters multiple times and executing multiple times is the way to go. Your proposed way is actually much slower and more prone to errors.